# Direct access to folder within joomla

Tags: access, subdirectory

In my Joomla, direct access to subfolders residing in the Joomla folder is forbidden, let's say I have

```
*Joomla
**PlainHTML
```

so an URL pointed directly to `PlainHTML` will produce `Error 404`, can we create an exception for this? so we can access the PlainHTML folder directly.

Comment: As I tested this, if I create a folder `myfolder` in Joomla root directory and place an `index.html` file into that folder, I am able to see that html file with the content of it at`http://myjoomla/myfolder` without any problem. So I cannot duplicate the problem.

Comment: I mean the issue you explain is coming from outside Joomla, maybe from .htaccess or server settings.